# Joomla 4 API rename attributes

Tags: joomla-api

In Laravel, you can use eloquent mutator transforms to change field names (database table column name) to a preferred/alias property name. How can this be done in Joomla 4?

I know I could do this in Joomla 4 JsonapiView:

```
protected function prepareItem($item)
{
   $item->nicername = $item->uglyname;
   unset($item->uglyname);
}
```

Is there a better approach for this? In the Serializer, it looks like only Relationships can be done.